# How to create variables for Facial_Recognition from database

Tags: python

I'm trying to be able to pull data from a database with a name and an image file name then put it into a `face_recognition` Python program. However, for the code that I'm using, the program learns the faces by calling variables with different names.

How can I create variables based on the amount of data that I have in the database?

What could be a better approach to solve this problem?

```
first_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("first.jpg")

first_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(first_image)[0]

second_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("second.jpg")

biden_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(second_image)[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use arrays instead of storing each image/encoding in an individual variable, and fill the arrays from a `for` loop.

Assuming you can change the filenames from `first.jpg`, `second.jpg`... to `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`... you can do this:

```
numberofimages = 10 # change this to the total number of images
images = [None] * (numberofimages+1) # create an array to store all the images
encodings = [None] * (numberofimages+1) # create an array to store all the encodings

for i in range(1, numberofimages+1):
    filename = str(i) + ".jpg" # generate image file name (eg. 1.jpg, 2.jpg...)

    # load the image and store it in the array
    images[i] = face_recognition.load_image_file(filename)
    # store the encoding
    encodings[i] = face_recognition.face_encodings(images[i])[0]
```

You can then access eg. the 3rd image and 3rd encoding like this:

```
image[3]
encoding[3]
```

If changing image file names is not an option, you can store them in a dictionary and do this:

```
numberofimages = 3 # change this to the total number of images
images = [None] * (numberofimages+1) # create an array to store all the images
encodings = [None] * (numberofimages+1) # create an array to store all the encodings
filenames = {
    1: "first",
    2: "second",
    3: "third"
}

for i in range(1, numberofimages+1):
    filename = filenames[i] + ".jpg" # generate file name (eg. first.jpg, second.jpg...)
    print(filename)
    # load the image and store it in the array
    images[i] = face_recognition.load_image_file(filename)
    # store the encoding
    encodings[i] = face_recognition.face_encodings(images[i])[0]
```

Comment: I had to use append instead of doing it with the index and now it works wonderfully, thank you so much!

Comment: @RodolfoArgüello Glad it helped. I changed `images[i-1]` and `encodings[i-1]` to `images[i]` and `encodings[i]` in the code snippets - should work with the index as well now.